# How to send MultipartContent correctly on Linux/MacOS?

Tags: c#, .net-core

On Windows, the following code works just fine, but on MacOS and on Linux it sends an empty body.

Here's the basics code flow:

```
// assume List<byte[]> parts; contains the body parts.
// assume targetURL contains the server's URL
// assume client is an HttpClient properly initialized.

var msg = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, targetURL);
var body= new MultipartContent("parallel", "boundary");
foreach(var part in parts)
{
    var mime = new ByteArrayContent(part);
    mime.Headers.ContentType = "application/octet-stream";
    mime.Headers.ContentLength = part.Length;
    body.Content.Add(mime);
}

msg.Content = body;
var result = await client.SendAsync(msg);
Console.WriteLine(String.Format("result.StatusCode = {0}", result.StatusCode));
if (result.StatusCode > 299)
    Console.WriteLine(Encoding.UTF8.GetString(result.Data));
```

I test with the command:

```
dotnet run
```

or

```
dotnet testProgram.dll
```

depending on where I am.

On Windows, the result is a 202 while on MacOS it is 400 with the message:

> Could not find beginning multipart boundary.

Sniffing in WireShark shows that the HTTP body is, in fact, empty!

So, what is the correct way to use `MultipartContent`?

Answer (score 0):

The way I found that worked seems hacky to me.

I'm posting it here just in case it is the correct answer, but I don't like it much.

```
...
//msg.Content = body;
msg.Content = new StreamContent(body.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);
var result = await client.SendAsync(msg);
...
```

It just seem wrong to convert a specific Content class to a (slightly more) generic Content class, before casting it to the base interface class HttpContent as it is given to the HttpRequestMessage.